# InstalledFontCollection don't List All Fonts in Windows Server 2012

Tags: .net, fonts, fastreport

I was installed two font Titr1 & Titr2 in windows server 2012. the Wordpad show two font correctly and usable. but FastReport not show two Font, Only show Font Titr2. but when Titr2 was removed the font Titr1 shown in FastReport.

first I was beilieved that this problem related to FastReport. but when List all Installed Font by below code, I'm realized that this Problem may be related to .Net.

```
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

foreach (FontFamily fa in installedFontCollection.Families)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fa.Name);
}
```

so My question is why .Net Can't Load All Font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that in Windows Server 2012 R2 despite windows server 2008 or win 7 only one regular, one bold, ... font of each family is loaded by >NET. so if two regular font have same family name only one of them will be load by .Net in windows server 2012 R2.